# How can I obtain a probability at specific x value in a gamma probability density function in Python scipy?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, probability-density, gamma-distribution

I can obtain the probability for x in a gamma distribution via the following in python

```py
import numpy as np 
from scipy.stats import gamma

# Gamma distribution
print(gamma.pdf(x=2, a=2, scale=1, loc=0)) # 0.27067
```

However, this requires creating a new gamma distribution every time I want to get the probably at a specific x.

I like to create a designated gamma distribution `my_gamma_dist`, then draw from this time and time again for a specific x value.

```py
import numpy as np 
from scipy.stats import gamma

my_gamma_dist = gamma.pdf(x, a=2, scale=1, loc=0)

my_gamma_dist.x = 2 # AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'x'
print(my_gamma_dist(x=2)) # TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I've checked the documentation but I'm still unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the distribution and later call the `.pdf` method on the values you are looking for, namely:

```py
from scipy.stats import gamma

g = gamma(a=2, scale=1, loc=0)

x=2
g.pdf(x)
0.2706705664732254

x=3
g.pdf(x)
0.14936120510359185

# Or pass a list of values to evaluate
g.pdf([2,3])
array([0.27067057, 0.14936121])
```